# Spring optimistic lock for MongoDB document with java.util.Date field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, optimistic-locking

I'm trying to implement optimistic locking for documents in an existing MongoDB database. Currently there is no `version` field and I would like to avoid adding it because we'll have to stop the application.

But there is a `lastModified` date field and it seems that I can make use of it like this:

```
@LastModifiedDate
@Version
private Date lastModified;
```

But when I marked this field as `@Version` and tried to save an item, I got the following exception:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Date] to type [java.lang.Number]

So, I also added Date to Number and Long to Date converters to my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    ...

    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(CustomConversions.StoreConversions.NONE,
            Arrays.asList(
                new DateToNumberConverter(),
                new LongToDateConverter()
        ));
    }
}
```

This works like a charm for existing documents. But when I try to add a new document, I get:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [java.util.Date]

If I then add an Integer to Date converter, then the new document is saved in the DB, but all the dates are now `NumberLong` instead of `ISODate`, i.e. was `"lastModified" : ISODate("2018-10-02T07:30:12.005Z")` and now `"lastModified" : NumberLong("1538465479364")`. This breaks the consistency between existing documents and new ones.

**So the questions are:**

1. Is there any possibility to use `java.util.Date` with `@Version` so that all dates are stored as `ISODate` in MongoDB?
2. Could anyone point to documentation on optimistic locking in Spring Data for MongoDB apart from this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.optimistic-locking ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like currently there is no possibility to use Date as a version field because it is cast to Number inside MongoTemplate.
I solved the issue by using my custom MongoTemplate that extends the Spring Data MongoTemplate and overrides required methods. Unfortunately I had to copy-paste a lot of code because the overriden logic is in private methods.